# NSXMLParser stop parsing and return entire NSXMLNode as string

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser, nsxml

How would I go about telling NSXMLParser to stop parsing a particular node, and just return all the inner content as a string?

for example:

```
<doc>
<hello><yes>no</yes><hello>
</doc>
```

i want to return `<yes>no</yes>` as a string, rather than drill down further

Comment: Change `<yes>no</yes>` to `&lt;yes>no&lt;/yes>` in the XML file and it will be treated at text. No need to fool the parser.

Comment: Tell us what problem you are trying to solve, and perhaps we can suggest a way of solving it that isn't quite so crazy.

Comment: I am parsing Xliff files which sometimes places  empty nodes within nodes to signify object placement. Currently I have no way of finding the position of the empty node within the target node to be able to recreate the Xliff file when I save.

A better (simplified) example would be like so:
<target>hello <x /> my name is<target>

I need to be able to recreate this structure. I could quite easily do this if nsxmlparser would return the entire target node.